# How to enable logging to a file in QuestDB docker container?

Tags: java, docker, questdb

I am running QuestDB as a docker container and mount my data directory to the hold as suggested in the start up docker guide

```
docker run -p 9000:9000 -v "$(pwd):/root/.questdb/" questdb/questdb
```

I can see logs using logs command

```
docker logs <containerid>
```

but I would like them to be permanently saved at the mounted host directory and I cannot find a way to do it. I only found a documentation mentioning a way to change logging configuration via adding something to classpath here https://questdb.io/docs/reference/configuration/#logging
but my Java classpath understanding is a bit shallow to make use of it, does anyone know a way how I can configure a container to add a system property `"system" property: -Dout=/something_else.conf` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save logs from `docker logs` you can read documentation here https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/. 
According to link you provided you can create conf/log.conf in the current directory with content provided. After starting container `docker run -p 9000:9000 -v "$(pwd):/root/.questdb/" questdb/questdb` you should have questdb-docker.log in your current directory with logs inside.

Comment: I am sure this option about conf/log.conf wasn't there in the docs when I posted the question, thanks for pointing it out